# How do I prevent an initializer script from running when I execute a test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, initialization, minitest, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm using a Rails 5.1 environment.  I have a script located at

```
config/initializers/websockets.rb
```

This is run when my server starts, however, I don't want this script to run when I execute tests, for instance ...

```
localhost:mine satishp$ rails test test/lib/websocket_client_test.rb
```

How do I prevent the initializers scripts from running when I'm executing my tests, or at least this specific file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializers are just Ruby scripts that are executed when Rails is starting up so you can put whatever code you want in them. In particular, you can look at `Rails.env`:

```
if(!Rails.env.test?)
  # Do whatever needs to be done...
end
```

or environment variables:

```
if(!ENV['SUPPRESS_WEB_SOCKET_INIT'])
   #...
end
```

and then set the `SUPPRESS_WEB_SOCKET_INIT` environment variable when you run your tests (or reverse the logic if that's a better fit).

These are blunt instruments though so you might want to reconsider your approach. Perhaps it would make more sense to initialize your websocket stuff the first time it is needed and then set up some mocks to replace the functionality in your tests.

Answer (score -1):

Move the initializer script out of the directory, then move it back afterward.

```
localhost:mine satishp$ mv $RUBY_DIRECTORY/config/initializers/websockets.rb /home/satishp && \
rails test test/lib/websocket_client_test.rb && \
cp /home/satishp/websockets.rb $RUBY_DIRECTORY/config/initializers/websockets.rb
```

Comment: Is there anything more environment-specific I can do?  I included one initializer script in my example, but if there are several, repeatedly moving files around may get cumbersome and also unintuitive for new people who are coming into the project and running tests.

Comment: The only thing is to have a script that deletes the initializers you don't want, and one more script that copies them back.  That way you just have to run the correct script before the test and the correct one after.

Comment: Ok.  I'm still pretty new at Rails and moving scripts around on the command line seems somewhat un-Rails to me. But if there is absolutely no other way, I'll accept.  Going to search around a little more.